# Why are the style classes removed from my element when it's appended?

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-5

Can you explain me how it works? Im trying to append div with content added by innerHTML and it's works, but with no styling classes.

```js
const el = document.createElement("div");

el.classList.add("col-sm-4", "col-md-3", "py-3");

el.innerHTML = `<div class="card border-primary">
                    <div class="card-body">
                    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/80" class="img-regular">
                    </div>
                </div>`
                
                
document.getElementById('gallery').appendChild(el);

// }); // commented out by community
```

```html
<div id="gallery"></div>
```

so... no bootstrap styling and mansory library also not working.

Comment: I converted your code to a snippet. Seems to work fine once I removed the extra characters at the end. Do you see errors in your console?

Comment: @isherwood It's works, but it's for fetching photos and after fetch and append i can't see styling. When I add those DIVs in html everything it's perfect. / Nah, just pure bootstrap and js.

Comment: Are you saying that the outer div simply has no class attribute on it? Can you apply other attributes?

Comment: SHow the actual code that gives you problems.

Comment: Ok guys Im really sorry. Ive made mistake with img class, so styling form bootstrap it's working fine, but masonry lib still works only when i add DIVs in html.

Answer (score 0):

You've got 2 opening `<div>`'s and 3 closing `</div>`s. Try removing the extra closing tag.

```js
const el = document.createElement("div");
el.classList.add("col-sm-4", "col-md-3", "py-3");
el.innerHTML = `<div class="card border-primary">
  <div class="card-body">
    <img src="${photo.urls.small}" class="img-regular">
  </div>
</div>`
gallery.appendChild(el);
```

Comment: You're right--tired eyes. Still, that probably wouldn't break the layout for that structure--just what comes after.

Comment: @Adrian - This was just an educated guess based on what you shared. If that didn't work you can either wait for someoen else to make another educated guess, or post enough code that we can replicate the problem. Without being able to replicate the problem all you'll get are educated guesses.